# How do I filter an Access subform with multiple combo boxes in the form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have multiple combo boxes in my form (acct_nbr, type, team_aud). I'm looking for a way to filter the subform (as a datasheet) based on the selection of each combo box. If a combo box is not used in the filter, the subform data just filters on the other two combo boxes.

Here is what I have so far:

```vb
Private Sub cboAccountFilter_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub cboTypeFilter_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub txtTeamAuditorFilter_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub FilterSubform()
    Dim strWhere As String

    If Nz(Me.cboAccountFilter, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[acct_nbr] = '" & Me.cboAccountFilter & " ' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.cboTypeFilter, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[Type] = '" & Me.cboTypeFilter & " ' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.txtTeamAuditorFilter, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[team_aud] = '" & Me.txtTeamAuditorFilter & " ' AND "
    End If

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 5)
        Me.fsubStatsDashPrimarySix.Form.Filter = strWhere
        Me.fsubStatsDashPrimarySix.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.fsubStatsDashPrimarySix.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.fsubStatsDashPrimarySix.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I do not receive an error when I click on one of the combo boxes, but all the data is filtered out.

Comment: Please format the source code correctly.

Comment: What happens when you eliminate the space before the single quote in each of these? --> `" ' AND "`  (ie change those to `"' AND "`)

Comment: You would also be wise to inspect the `strWhere` string as it exists when you assign it to `Filter`.  Add `Debug.Print strWhere`, run the code, and view its output in the Immediate window.  (Ctrl+g will take you there.)

Answer (score 2):

Change your filters to this:

```
If Nz(Me.cboAccountFilter, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[acct_nbr] = '" & Trim(Me.cboAccountFilter) & "' AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.cboTypeFilter, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[Type] = '" & Trim(Me.cboTypeFilter) & "' AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.txtTeamAuditorFilter, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[team_aud] = '" & Trim(Me.txtTeamAuditorFilter) & "' AND "
End If
```

## Edit:

As per your comment, I think it would be:

```
strWhere = strWhere & "[team_aud] LIKE *'" & Trim(Me.txtTeamAuditorFilter) & "'* AND "
```

(I tried to leave that as a comment, but the asterisks were interpreted as italics due to SO's markup language).

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!

How would I change the txtTeamAuditorFilter to a contains instead of an equals?