# Subform filtering based off multiple parameters (Combobox AND Textbox)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, subform

I want to filter a subform based on two parameters on a form (combobox and textbox).

I have a Form with combobox cboTimePeriod which show data from table TimePeriod (example TimePeriod=”10.01.2018-10.02.2018”; ID=12).

Combobox data:

Data Row source= SELECT [tblTimePeriod].[TimePeriod], [tblTimePeriod].[ID] FROM tblTimePeriod ORDER BY [TimePeriod];

Data Bound Column=2 (bound to ID)

Format Column Count=1 (shows textual value of TimePeriod)
Format List Width=2,54cm

Also I have some cbobuttons with Cities, so when I press a button named "Boston", TextBox txtCity shows i.e. “Boston”.

What I want is when ever I select time period (cboTimePeriod), result in a subform has to be filtered based on these two parameters (selected TimePeriod AND City in textbox).

And as you might guessed, it does not work.

I tried several codes, here is the one I've used:

'[How do I filter an Access subform with multiple combo boxes in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511226/how-do-i-filter-an-access-subform-with-multiple-combo-boxes-in-the-form)

And this is my implementation, which does not work:

```
Dim strWhere As String

 If Nz(Me.cboTimePeriod, "") <> "" Then
strWhere = strWhere & "[TimePeriodID] = '" & Trim(Me. cboTimePeriod) & " ' AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.txtSelectedCity, "") <> "" Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "[CityName] = '" & Trim(Me. txtSelectedCity) & " ' AND "
End If

If strWhere <> "" Then
    strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 5)
    Me.qry_SomeData_subform.Form.Filter = strWhere 'after this line, function exits the code        
Me.qry_ SomeData_subform.Form.FilterOn = True
Else    
    Me.qry_ SomeData_subform.Form.Filter = ""      
    Me.qry_ SomeData_subform.Form.FilterOn = False
End If
```

strWhere gives this:
`strWhere = "[TimePreriodID] = '12 ' AND [CityName] = 'Boston '"`

After aplying a filter, on a subform "Unfiltered" changes to "Filtered", but with no change in data.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess TimePeriod is *numeric*, thus (and correction the spaces):

```
strWhere = strWhere & "[TimePeriodID] = " & Me!cboTimePeriod.Value & " AND "
```

and:

```
strWhere = strWhere & "[CityName] = '" & Trim(Me!txtSelectedCity.Value) & "' AND "
```

**Edit**:
To look up another column, here the second column:

```
strWhere = strWhere & "[CityName] = '" & Trim(Me!txtSelectedCity.Column(1)) & "' AND "
```

Comment: No success; First condition with the correction, without second condition, works.

Comment: In Immediate window print strWhere returns:  [TimePeriodID] = 13 AND which is correct.

Comment: Adding a correction as you suggested resulted with strWhere value in Immediate window like this:  
[TimePeriodID] = 12  AND [CityName] = 'Boston'    
But subform data is not filtered. Nothing happened.

Comment: If it filters correctly with TimePeriod only, you probably don't have a CityName of "Boston".

Comment: When I press comboBox "Boston", txtSelectedCity = "Boston".    
The same text is in the tblCity.    
But. When I changed txtbox to combobox, and changed    
strWhere=strWhere & "[CityID] = " & Trim(Me.cboCity) & "  AND " it works.
But it's not the solution. What puzzles me is  how to get it to work with string.

Comment: I guess it's apllying string filter on numerical field (CityID).

Comment: Can't see why _that shouldn't be the solution_. The ID is the value to search for. But to use the cityname, see my edited answer.

Comment: True, I fixed it.
Now I have other problem, I'll try to figure it out myself, but time is not my friend.