# MSAccess VBA, filtering query results via combo box (text)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to filter date values (text) in a query based on a comboBox text value.
Here is what I have:

ComboBoxTimePeriod (ID [num], TimePeriod [text]).

In ComboBox I select Time period, like "16.10.2017-15.11.2017".

In a query I have Date field with single date, like "20.10.2017" (text).

What I want is to write an SQL code which searches for all records with date within TimePeriod range.

So far Idea is to extract SatrtDate and EndDate from TimePeriod like this:

```
    Dim strStartDate As String
    Dim strEndDate As String

    strStartDate = Mid(Me.cboTimePeriod.Text, 1, 10)
    strEndDate = Mid(Me.cboTimePeriod.Text, 12, 10)
```

Now from TimePeriod "16.10.2017-15.11.2017" I have StartDate (16.10.2017) and EndDate (15.11.2017).

And I want to filter all records which have date within those two dates.
This is where I need you guys.

Note that this is different issue from my last question, where I searched for a records with TimePeriodID ([Subform filtering based off multiple parameters (Combobox AND Textbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826413/subform-filtering-based-off-multiple-parameters-combobox-and-textbox/48826597#48826597)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always handle dates as Date, not text:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
StartDate = DateValue(Split(Me.cboTimePeriod.Value, "-")(0))
EndDate = DateValue(Split(Me.cboTimePeriod.Value, "-")(1))
```

The build your filter:

```
... " Between #" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(EbdDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

To filter a form:

```
Me.Filter = "[Date Field] Between #" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(EbdDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

And do make sure that your *Date Field* is of data type Date, not Text.

Comment: StartDate and EndDate worked after changing .Value to .text.
When it was value, it was ID, not text, so result was "00:00:00".
Now it's fine.
Still working on applying it to code, since I'm novice in programming.

Comment: Can't get it to work. This is my modification, since I have more than one subform in a form:
    Me.qry_FSW_services_subform.Form.Filter = "[ qry_FSW_services_subform].[V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE] Between #" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

Comment: It should probably read: `Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.Filter = "[V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE] Between ... `

Comment: In Emmediate window result is:    [V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE] Between ## And ##

Comment: Same result with your mod in immediate window:        [V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE]  Between ## And ##

Comment: Well, variables `StartDate` and `EndDate` must first be assigned the date values to filter on.

Comment: Now values are correct: Between #16/10/2017# And #15/11/2017#, but it's not applied to my form data (Filter is active).
    In Immediate window a value for V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE is 00:00:00 (it's defined as Date, just like strStartDate and EndDate).

Comment: The dd/mm/yyyy format will fail, not for these valus but where day is between 1 and 12. So change it back to have `Between #2017/10/16# And #2017/10/15#` returned.

Comment: Your'e a very patien guy Gustav.    I changed it back. But there is something wrong with V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE definition, since a value is 00:00:00.

Comment: But `[V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE]` is the field in you subform. You can make it visible in the form to study the values. If they are _Null_, the filter will exclude them.

Comment: Make sure the field is of data type _Date_, not Text.

Comment: Gustav, many thanks for your help. Your code works. If you write correct query in a code. All the time I tried to filter Date field in a query with simmilar name, but there is no Date field..
What can I say..
Thanks again.

Comment: It was partly a joke. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's OK. I like thiks being done properly. Thank's for a tip. I'm kinda new here.