# Query with multiple parameters not working (Microsoft Access)

Tags: ms-access

I have a huge list of documents and I have made a database to consolidate and make searching for relevant documents easier.

***View of the UI:***

[image]

For the text box, I used the following code:

```
SELECT Combined.*
FROM Combined
WHERE (([Combined].[File Name] & [Title]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![search].[Text] & "*")
```

For the combo box, I used the following:

```
SELECT Combined.*
FROM Combined
WHERE ((Combined.Category) Like [Forms]![Search]![Combo7].[Text])
```

Individually both of these work fine, However, I wanted to have it so that I can select the category and have the text box search within that category so I used AND to combine the parameters like so:

```
SELECT Combined.*
FROM Combined
WHERE ((([Combined].[File Name] & [Title]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![search].[Text] & "*") AND ((Combined.Category) Like [Forms]![Search]![Combo7].[Text]));
```

Now it only works with the combo box. So as soon I select an option from the combo box, it populates the table however as soon as I type anything in the text box, the results disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use Text property. Use Value. And since Value is default property for data controls don't even have to type it. LIKE without wildcard might as well use = sign. Otherwise, as far as I can tell, what you have should work - does for me.

Comment: Haha. Thanks. That was the issue. Its hilarious how such a small thing can make me waste 2 hours. I changed [Combo7].[Text] to [Combo7] and it worked like a charm

Comment: You can filter subform data directly by field name. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826413/subform-filtering-based-off-multiple-parameters-combobox-and-textbox).

Answer (score 0):

A control must retain focus for Text property to be available. When you type into textbox the combobox no longer has focus. Although, because of textbox Text property, I am surprised it worked when combobox had focus. The LIKE and wildcard must have somehow handled the resulting error. Also, if you click a button to open query or requery form, then combobox does not have focus and should still fail. More mystery. There is seldom a reason to use Text property.

Use Value property. Since Value is default property of data controls, don't even have to type it.

A LIKE operator without wildcard might as well be = sign.